# Java Connect Over A Socket Using Public IP Address

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip

I'm basically trying to connect to other computer. Everything works as I want once I use "localhost" as the IP address. If I try to put in my public IP, my client cannot find the server running although it is. If I switch it to "localhost" it works again.

I'm using a router or a modem or how do you call these things to split internet for 4 people + wireless. I have my port forwarded, but I still can't get it to work. What are the problems I might be encountering? I don't think this is the problem with the code since everything works properly with "localhost", unless I need to do something extra when switching to public IP.

I also tried to disable firewall and it still didn't work. When I checked what is my IP address it is said that my IP is static, but I don't see the difference.

Any thoughts/ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible problems I can think of:

1. You didn't forward your ports correctly, or there's some other problem with your router configuration. In that case, your question is better asked on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).
2. Your server is listening only on your loopback interface. Make sure in your server code you have it set to listen on 0.0.0.0, or whatever your library/OS equivalent is.

Comment: I have ran a minecraft server successfully after some attempts, but it worked. Can't remember what I did to make it work though o-o. My server is listening on 0.0.0.0. As for router, I have configured port or something to run 1234 port UDP/TCP. 1234 is what my program uses. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

**I have found my problem. I was doing everything correctly. And everything works correctly. The problem is that my router can't connect to itself using my static(external/public) IP. Other people can connect to my external/public IP properly.**

Comment: So how did you fix this?